# Clicked state; styling on groups of form controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of radio controls in a form. Each one is wrapped in a `<label>` element for styling.

When the page loads, each label has a background color set on it via `CSS`.

I want a user to be able to click on any radio button from the group toggling it's parent `<label>` background color.

From a UX point of view, I need each checked control to have it's parent label background color toggled. I need this throughout the group of radio controls.

```
<form>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question1">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question1">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question1">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question2">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question2">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question2">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question3">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question3">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question3">
</label>
```

My approach;

I'm aware one cant select a parent element using `CSS` so it's off to jQuery.

Using jQuery, I can apply some logic to the *entire* set of radio buttons like so:

```
$(':radio').each( function (i, el) {
 $(this).on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent().css('background', '#ba9bc9');
    }
    $(this).on('blur', function(){
         $(this).parent().css('background', '#09afed');
    });
 });
});
```

This works, however it only works for the current element selected. Clicking away loses focus. I need it to maintain state throughout the entire set of questions. So questions #1 - #3 could all end up with coloured backgrounds potentially.

Comment: When a radio button gets checked, find all the other radio buttons with the same name, and remove their style.

Comment: So you want to change a colour of a label that wraps a radio when said radio is clicked?

Comment: Does your label need to wrap your radio?

Comment: Label needs to wrap radio I'm afraid.

Comment: Since the code is generated using a WP plugin I have no or little control over the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the radios with the same name, and remove the class from them, before adding the class to the radio that was clicked.

```js
var $radios = $(':radio');

$radios.on('click', function(e){
  $radios.filter('[name="'+ e.target.name +'"]').not(e.target).parent().removeClass('selected');
  $(e.target).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red; //or whatever
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question1">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question1">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question1">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question2">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question2">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question2">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question3">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question3">
</label>
<label>     
 <input type="radio" name="question3">
</label>
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able and willing to refacter your code you can do this purely with css:

```css
label {
  background: #ccc;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: #b00;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="lbl01" type="radio" name="question1">
  <label for="lbl01">01</label>
  <input id="lbl02" type="radio" name="question1">
  <label for="lbl02">02</label>
  <input id="lbl03" type="radio" name="question1">
  <label for="lbl03">03</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="lbl04" type="radio" name="question2">
  <label for="lbl04">04</label>
  <input id="lbl05" type="radio" name="question2">
  <label for="lbl05">05</label>
  <input id="lbl06" type="radio" name="question2">
  <label for="lbl06">06</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="lbl07" type="radio" name="question3">
  <label for="lbl07">07</label>
  <input id="lbl08" type="radio" name="question3">
  <label for="lbl08">08</label>
  <input id="lbl09" type="radio" name="question3">
  <label for="lbl09">09</label>
</form>
```